# iOS - How to add custom image and 2 tables to UI View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I bring this question regarding a project work which is rather complex. I want to notify you that I never coded on iOS before and this is my debut, but in some good light, I have a good knowledge of programming. After few hours of work I managed to create the 1st part of the project, but now I am stuck on the second part of the project due to the multiple features the app has. I posted you a picture with the demo, it's on an Android device, I want to make it on iOS.

I will describe a little the project. On this 'page' the application has 3 parts. In the 1st part which named by me`Feature 1` I have a picture, a photo of a plane. The photo is all gray, but if I tap one of those 3 parts I marked with 3 different colors: red, blue and green which corespond with the back, wings and front of the plane, that area will get colored specificly. e.g: All plane is gray, if I tap the back of the plane, the back of the plane will turn red, while the remaining 2 parts are gray. This feature will show me what part of the plane I chosed.

Here I am thinking at placing 4 photos, the original one (full gray) and other 3 photos in with each side marked and colored specificly (back red, wings gray, front gray; back gray, wings blue, front gray; back gray; wings gray; front green) and 3 invisible buttons for each section. If the person tap the wings for example, he will tap the invisible button placed over the wings and that will trigger the new picture to be displayed.

The second part, `Feature 2` has a direct conection with `Feature 1`. Basically, `feature 2` is a list of the parts which regards the are selected. For example, if we selected wings on `feature 1`, on `Feature 2` I will have a list of elements displayed, e.g: `long wings, short wings`. Let me tell you from the beggining that all will be stored localy. My questing here is, what should I use to populate and display the list of items to show like shopping list (like in image).

After we displayed the list, we can see that every element has in corner a [+] button. This will populate the area called `Feature 3`. Selecting an item from `Feature 2` will move it to `Feature 3`. `Feature 3` will be like our Shopping bag and the items we chosed. We selected to buy a bread, we erase bread from `feature 2` because stock is out now, and we placed in `feature 3` our shopping bag.

Shall I use UI View Controller of UI Table View Controller? Also can you tell me in detail what I should chose for every feature in particular and why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIViewController` if you only have 3 features. Then you can create three `UIViews` and and them as subviews inside the view controller.

Use should not use UITableViewController because it is not optimal here. It is good to use table when you have data source (for example from .plist or from an array) to fill into each cell of table. But here you have just three views, so just use UIViewController.

Comment: At `feature 2` I want to populate the cells of the table from an array.

Comment: you can use a UITableView in feature 2 instead of a UIView. But the overall controller should be UIViewController. Hence, first feature : UIView, second: UITableView, 3rd: UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Add the a `UIImageView` and 2 `UITableView`s to your `UIViewController` in the Main.Storyboard. Then cmd + click from each view to the other, and select equal height. Then all 3 of them will be next to each other with equal heights.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, all of these are dependent of each other and as per your UI for feature 2 and 3, I think you should use only one tableview in your UIViewcontroller and use this as per your UI requirements as follows.

1. feature 1 : UIImageView
2. Feature 2 : UITableView1 Section1
3. Feature 3 : UITableView1 Section2